# JQuery Navigation Highlight with dropmenu.js

Tags: jquery, navigation, highlight

I'm new to JQuery but am finding it really useful. I'm trying to highlight the navigation item for the current page a user is on using JQuery. I've tried several of the techniques I've found that are similar, but I can't get anything to work quite right and I wonder if it's because I'm using dropmenu.js and that may be causing some issues.

I've created a CSS class called .selected which does what I need it to when applied manually to a nav item. I've then got the following JQuery code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#nav-one li a').click(function() {
$(this).closest("li").addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
return(false);  
});
</script>
```

And my menu looks like this:

```
<ul id="nav-one" class="dropmenu css-only">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="our_cupcakes.html">Our Cupcakes</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="birthday_cupcakes.html">Birthday Cupcakes</a></li>
<li><a href="new_baby_cupcakes.html">New Baby Cupcakes</a></li>
<li><a href="anniversary_cupcakes.html">Anniversary Cupcakes</a></li>
<li><a href="just_because_cupcakes.html">Just Because Cupcakes</a></li>
<li><a href="seasonal_cupcakes.html">Seasonal Cupcakes</a></li>
<li><a href="special_order_cupcakes.html">Special Order Cupcakes</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="flavours_and_colours.html">Flavours &amp; Colours</a></li>
<li><a href="faqs.html">FAQs</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="faqs.html">General questions</a></li>
<li><a href="faqs.html#ingredients">Ingredients</a></li>
<li><a href="faqs.html#delivery">Delivery &amp; Pick-up</a></li>
<li><a href="faqs.html#about">About us</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</li>
<li><a href="order_cupcakes.php">Order Cupcakes</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Dropmenu.js does my drop menu work and there's a separate CSS for that, but I can't see this would stop me from applying the .selected class to a nav item using JQuery, but I could be wrong.

Is anyone able to give me some hints on where I may be going wrong please? Eventually the code will sit on my wife's home baking website http://cupcakes.ladybirdbakery.co.uk

Many thanks.

Ant

Comment: Are you wrapping your code in `$(document).ready(function(){...})`?

Comment: Hi there Abraham,

Thank you for your response. Although I had forgotten to do that, I've done it now but it hasn't solved the issue. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Is this the correct behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/Jewkw/1

Comment: Pretty much, I wouldn't need the child items from the drop down menu to highlight when the main level is clicked, so on the jsfiddle example when I click 'Our cupcakes' all those indented below it highlight currently as well. But essentially that looks like that's pretty much working with the code I was using. I wonder why it's not working on my page then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 2**:
I didn't realize you were trying to highlight the menu option for the page the user was on. That's a totally different thing, and what you're doing now is the wrong way to approach i, and here's why: When a user clicks on a link, the class `selected` is added to the `<li>`. But  then a *totally new page* is loaded. ***The changes JavaScript (and jQuery) make to a webpage do not persist for future pages.*** So that means when the new page is loaded, none of the `<li>`s have the `selected` class, until someone clicks on one (but then another page will load immediately, so they will not see the `li` highlight).
As far as how to implement this, I would recommend just manually adding the class `selected` to the correct `li` in each HTML file. But if you really want to use JavaScript, here's the code:

```
$(function(){ // this is a shortcut for $(document).ready(function(){
  var filename = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
  $('a[href="' + (filename ? filename : 'index.html') + '"]').parent('li').addClass('selected')
})
```

So first we create a variable `filename` and set it to the filename of the current page. Then we find all `<a>`s whose `href` attribute is equal to the filename, get their parent `<li>` elements, and add the class `selected`.
I hope this helps. If you have more problems or questions, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there Abraham, thanks again for your suggestions. I'm sorry but it still isn't working, I've uploaded it (index.html only) to cupcakes.ladybirdbakery.co.uk and it's actually breaking the drop nav a little now. I just don't know enough about JQuery yet to get this right and I do hope that I'm not wasting your time.

Thanks so far. 

Ant

Comment: Don't worry, you're not wasting my time. :) I'm glad to help. It can be hard for a newbie to get started, and I want to help you as much as I can.

Comment: Good morning, yes JQuery is a big leap forward in terms of my coding knowledge for sure, but it'll be great once I've got it under my belt. I've tried the above changes but it actually stopped the drop nav from working, I've moved it over to a beta folder here so you can see: http://cupcakes.ladybirdbakery.co.uk/beta/ removing the noConflict from the dropmenu.js didn't cause any issue, it was adding the click function to the dropmenu script on index.html that seems to have done it.

Comment: OK, the problem here is that you added some CSS for `.selected` that messes up the menu. Specifically, the `height: 19px` is causing the problem. Removing that line of CSS should fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I needed some CSS to style the selected state, I've removed that line, navigation is working again but it's not highlighting the page that it is on still. I tried without the CSS entirely as well (just in case) and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Now there's a different problem on the test site. You forgot the `return false` in the `click` event handler.

Comment: Sorry, I thought we removed that earlier, my mistake, I've put it back in. Thankyou. Ant.

Comment: You also need another closing `})` to end the `document.ready`. Sorry I didn't catch that earlier.

Comment: Thank you Abraham. We're getting closer now. If you click on the navigation items they now highlight. Home isn't highlighted when you first land on the page but if you click it, it applies the .selected class. Only issue now is that the navigation links themselves don't take you to the page, but hopefully that's a simple fix. 

Cheers, 

Ant

Comment: Ah, are you trying to highlight the page the user is on? That's a totally different thing. See above.

Comment: Sorry, yes that's what I was trying to do. I'd like to use the Java in case the site ever grows or 

I do another site and I use an include for the navigation, as I wouldn't be able to apply the li 

class to each item then. 

With the code you've provided, newbie question I know, for the homepage for example, is it just a 

matter of adding $('li:has(a[href="index.html"' + location.pathname.slice(1) + '"])').addClass

('selected') or would I need to do something with the location.pathname.slice bit as well?

Comment: It should be exactly as I wrote in my answer above. Don't put 'index.html' or any filename in it - I'll explain above how it works.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that in such detail, that really helps. I've popped that code on to all of the pages in the beta folder as per the code you've supplied above. I'm afraid it still isn't working though, maybe I've done something wrong when putting it in the head?

Comment: So sorry - that was my fault, bug in the code. Fixed and tested.

Comment: Awesome, that works beautifully Abraham. Thank you so so much for all of your help and patience, I really appreciate it, it's a great little piece of code. Have a great rest of your day. Ant.

Comment: Glad this helps. I'll be ready to help you if you have any more questions. :)